# Debian based portable Linux distro

Tags: usb, portable, linux-distribution, debian

I read about a [Porteus](http://www.porteus.org/), a Linux distro which is designed to be run from USB.

I liked everything about it, but I prefer distros that are Debian derivatives. (Like Debian itself, Mint, Ubuntu, etc.)

I am interested in something similar to Porteus, but based on Debian. I want to have all my applications, data, settings, etc. around with me on a flash drive and be able to boot into it from a variety of computers. I'm not interested in a "persistent" Live USB, I want a real installation, a distro which is made to be portable.

I realize that I could just install Debian or Ubuntu on a flash drive. But that's not what I'm asking for. I'm asking for a distro that is *built* with portability in mind, like Porteus.

I have heard about "[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/)", but it seems so tiny and lightweight. The computers I use typically have decent hardware. Is there a more full distro out there that will fit my needs?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html). While it usually boots from a CD, it can use a stick for your home directory – and AFAIR you can move the entire system to the stick as well.

Comment: @Izzy If it usually boots from CD, will it save my changes in applications, settings, data, etc from boot to boot, so that I can work across different devices and keep my apps and work with me?

Comment: As I wrote: it gives you the option to do so on a USB-stick (or SD-card). *Knoppix* then uses a kind of "overlay file system" to blend that writable storage in with the system (as it does for installs and everything else).

Comment: @Izzy Is it automatic when I burn the ISO to the USB, or do I have to do something maually to configure it in that way?

Comment: If I could tell that, I'd made it an answer :) I'm not sure, but I'd say yes: the stick is not read-only, so I see no reason for a restriction to read-only. It is an *option* however when running it from the CD.

Comment: @Izzy Cool, I'll give it a try. Might post an answer here eventually.

Comment: Great! If you tried it and it fits, definitely consider to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :) Good luck!

Comment: Try installing any Linux distro on an external USB HDD, as you would normally install it on the computer.
I've had success with a Ubuntu 16.04 being moved between two very different computers and it worked fine. I also have a Mint install on an external HDD, and it doesn't seem to cause problems (I haven't tested it on other machines, so although unlikely, it may be different for you).

Answer (score 1):

[DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) small Linux distro was developed as an experiment to see how many usable desktop applications can fit inside a 50MB live CD. With the time this project expanded into a large community with thousands of developers dedicating their efforts to DSL. You get fully automated remote and local application installation system and a very versatile backup and restore system which may be used with any writable media including a USB device, floppy disk, or a hard drive.